# "ORA-12541: TNS:no listener" from Ubuntu 22.04 and Docker:PHP:8.0-fpm

Tags: laravel, oracle, docker, oracle11g, ubuntu-22.04

As part of our work, we were asked to create an Laravel application using existing Oracle Database data.
However, we cannot connect to Oracle from either the Docker container we are using for development or the Ubuntu 22.04 machine we are developing on.

The following code is the docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile used to create the container. In the code below, instantclient uses 11.2.0.4.0 to match the database version, but the latest version, 21.11.0.0.0, is still the same.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  xxxxx_calender_php:
    container_name: xxxxx_calender_php
    build:
      context: ./php
    ports:
      - '8087:80'
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./apache/default.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
      - ./apache/logs:/var/log/apache2
    restart: always
    extra_hosts:
      - "xxxxx:xxx.xx.xxx.x"
```

Dockefile

```
FROM php:8.0-fpm
COPY php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/instantclient/
ENV TNS_ADMIN /usr/local/instantclient/

COPY instantclient-basic-linux.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip /tmp
COPY instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip /tmp
COPY instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip /tmp

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y git openssh-client zlib1g-dev mariadb-client vim libzip-dev libpq-dev libonig-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-dev zip unzip \
  && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-jpeg \
  && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
  && docker-php-ext-install zip pdo_pgsql mbstring bcmath

#Composer install
RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
RUN php composer-setup.php
RUN php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
RUN mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

#Oracle Client
RUN apt-get install -y libaio1 wget && \
    unzip /tmp/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip -d /usr/local/ && \
    unzip /tmp/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip -d /usr/local/ && \
    unzip /tmp/instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip -d /usr/local/ && \
    ln -s /usr/local/instantclient_11_2 /usr/local/instantclient && \
    ln -s /usr/local/instantclient_11_2/libclntsh.so.11.1 /usr/local/instantclient/libclntsh.so && \
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/instantclient && \
    docker-php-ext-configure oci8 --with-oci8=instantclient,/usr/local/instantclient && \
    docker-php-ext-install oci8 && \ 
    docker-php-ext-configure pdo_oci --with-pdo-oci=instantclient,/usr/local/instantclient,11.1 && \
    docker-php-ext-install pdo_oci && \
    rm -rf /usr/local/*.zip

RUN echo "export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/local/instantclient \n\
export PATH=/usr/local/instantclient:${PATH}" >> ~/.bashrc

ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER 1

ENV COMPOSER_HOME /composer

ENV PATH $PATH:/composer/vendor/bin

#WORKDIR /var/www
# WORKDIR /workspace

RUN composer global require "laravel/installer"

RUN groupadd --force -g 1000 xxxx
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash --no-user-group -g xxxx -u 1000 xxxx
```

Laravel .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=oracle
DB_HOST=xxx.xx.xxx.x
DB_PORT=1521
DB_DATABASE=xxxxx
DB_USERNAME=xxxxx
DB_PASSWORD=xxxxx
```

The following `ORA-12541` error occurred from both the Docker container and Ubuntu itself.

```
xxxx@xxxxxxxxxxx:~$ sqlplus xxxxx/xxxxx@//xxx.xx.xxx.x:1521/xxxxx

SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Thu Oct 19 16:50:45 2023
Version 21.11.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2022, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12541: TNS:no listener
```

```
root@93ee8a37f9e7:/var/www/html/prinos_calender# php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.11.22 (PHP 8.0.30 — cli) by Justin Hileman
> DB::connection()->getConfig();

   WARNING  oci_connect(): ORA-12541: TNS:no listener in vendor/yajra/laravel-pdo-via-oci8/src/Pdo/Oci8.php on line 144.


   Yajra\Pdo\Oci8\Exceptions\Oci8Exception  ORA-12541: TNS:no listener.

>
```

However, Windows machines connected to the same network can connect normally.

```
PS C:\Users\xxxxxxx> sqlplus xxxxxx/xxxxxx@//xxx.xx.xxx.x:1521/xxxxx

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.1.0 Production on 木 10月 19 17:12:02 2023

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.



Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
に接続されました。
SQL>
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Check the basic ORA-12541 error tips at https://docs.oracle.com/en/error-help/db/ora-12541/. Check Docker networking.